# How to get image size uploaded by GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use GAE to upload picture,and use google.appengine.api.images to resize it.but I'd like to get the original size of this picture uploaded.i try to use image.width and image.height.but got int is not callable error.soi appreciate any help.

please see the code below:

```
class PictureUploader( webapp.RequestHandler ):
    WANNA_RATIO_ = 0.833333 # icon width : height | 100 : 120
    MAX_RATIO_ = 0.913043 # 105 : 115
    MIN_RATIO_ = 0.76 # 95 : 125
    def get( self ):
        self.post()

    def post( self ):
        if not check_session(self):
            self.redirect('login', True)

        from google.appengine.api import images   
        image_ = images.Image( self.request.get( 'picture' ) )

        from decimal import Decimal   
        i_width = Decimal( image_.size[0] )
        i_height = Decimal( image_.size[1] )
        w_h_ratio = i_width / i_height 
        if PictureUploader.MIN_RATIO_ > w_h_ratio: # picture too narrow
            h_ratio = i_height/120
            expected_w = Decimal("%.6f"%(i_width/h_ratio))
            image_ = images.resize(image_,expected_w,120)
        elif PictureUploader.MAX_RATIO_ < w_h_ratio: # picture too short
            w_ratio = i_width/100
            expected_h = Decimal("%.6f"%(i_height/w_ratio))
            image_ = images.resize(image_,100,expected_h)
        else:
            image_ = images.resize( image_, 100, 120 )

        models.Life(user = self.session['key'],pictureblob=image_).put()
```

you see image_.size[0], it doesn't work.

Comment: The error `int is not callable` seems to indicate that you accidently placed () after a property name, ie you had `image.height()` when it should have been just `image.height`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
image.height
image.width
```

the error you are getting means you are calling those properties like:

```
image.height() -> wrong
image.width()  -> wrong
```

Comment: sorry, it still doesn't work, i don't know whether i'm right or not about using GAE API, if i'm totally wrong, please correct me. let me detail me problem, i'm not sure with two point :  1. see here"  image_ = images.Image( self.request.get( 'picture' ) )" , you might know GAE and picture is a ' input type="file"', so i don't know could image object created like this; 2.if Q1 is all right, i correct codes like this "height = image_._height width = image_._width" and i used reflect to see whether those attributes were there(they are truly existed.), but i got NoneType:None .

Comment: there is no `size` attribute on the image. use `image.width` and `image.height` and you will get the values you want. i just tried it and it works fine but `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'size'`

Comment: yes. it works. oh, i forget how i got that kind of error, now i get a new one, when i put it into datastore, "RequestTooLargeError: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large." occurred. can you comment this or any solution.

Comment: i guess your file is bigger than 1mb which is the limit for a datastore entity. you should store the file in the blobstore a and reference it with a `BlobKeyProperty`. to write the file to the blobstore you should use the files api (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) if your not uploading the files via upload url.

Comment: Hi, i saw this just now, but i can't found out how to put image into db.BlobProperty without "RequestTooLargeError  The request to API call datastore_v3.Put%28 was too large." this error,there is not change to code on storing part%28last line. if i don't resize picture to a small one, error occurred. can you help.

Comment: store the image as a blob into the blobstore (not as a datastore blob) with the files api (link above) and then save the entity with the blobkey.